# Counting frequencies with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I'm having a data frame with two columns id_1 and id_2. For each of id_1, I want to count the number of matches it has with all the elements of id_2.

I imagine the result being a data frame with columns id_1, id_2 and number_of_id_2_found_for_id_1.

Here's what I'm trying

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  id_1 = sample(1:10, size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  id_2 = sample(1:10, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

df %>% group_by(id_1, id_2) %>%
  # id_1 should be unique
  summarise(~n(.x)) # I want this to be the number of id_2 it has found for each of the elements of id_1
```

My expected output would be:

1    1   0
1    2   0
1    3   0
1    4   1
1    5   0
....
1    9   0
2    1   0
...
2    7   1
2    8   0
2    9   1

And so on, basically for each id_1 the number of elements it has found for each_id_2. In the example above it's mostly 1, but in a lot bigger data frame the count would increase. This is like a bipartite graph where the edge would be the number of left-to-right matches between the first component - id_1 and id_2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, typo. Corrected it just now.

Comment: From the seed you mentioned, I get a row for `1 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated post, may be we need to do a `crossing` to return all the combinations, do a `count` on the original dataset for both columns and join with the full combination

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(id_1 = 1:10, id_2 = 1:10)  %>% 
  left_join(., df %>% 
                  count(id_1, id_2)) %>%
  mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
#    id_1  id_2     n
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0
# 2     1     2     0
# 3     1     3     1
# 4     1     4     1
# 5     1     5     0
# 6     1     6     0
# 7     1     7     0
# 8     1     8     0
# 9     1     9     1
#10     1    10     0
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: I actually want to see what the element is, i.e. a data frame of id_1, id_2, number_of_id_2_found_for_id_1

Comment: This gives a data frame with two columns, I want a data frame with 3 columns - a unique id_1, id_2, and a number of matches of id_2 for that id_1.

Comment: I added an edit with how I imagine the end result to be

Comment: @Nikola Thanks, I didn't notice it.  Please do mention when you edit it.  thanks

Comment: @Nikola I added a solution.  WIthout the full expected output, I am just guessing that this could be the output you wanted